# python : 2D perspective projection of a 3D surface plot

Tags: python, 3d, matplotlib, projection

I am making a 3D surface plot using matplotlib (python). I want to visualize the shadow **(2D perspective projection)** of the 3D surface on xy xz and yz surface.

In matlab, [SHADOWPLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6400-shadowplot) does the needed work. Does anyone know if Python has something similar that can be used for the same?

Comment: Have a look at this example from the Matplotlib gallery: http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/contourf3d_demo2.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Example from** [{here}](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/contourf3d_demo2.html):

```
"""
.. versionadded:: 1.1.0
   This demo depends on new features added to contourf3d.
"""

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.05)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=8, cstride=8, alpha=0.3)
cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, zdir='z', offset=-100, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, zdir='x', offset=-40, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, zdir='y', offset=40, cmap=cm.coolwarm)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_xlim(-40, 40)
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_ylim(-40, 40)
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_zlim(-100, 100)

plt.show()
```

**and result:**

[image]